# Weighted random with two weights

Tags: php, algorithm, random

In PHP I need to pick a random number between 1 and 100 with two weights.   These weights can also be between 1 and 100.  If both weights are low I would need the random number weighted low, high weighted high.  If one weight is high and one is low, or if they are both mid ranged, I would expect random number to be weighted random around the 50s.

I'm not sure the best way to go about this.  Any advice would be great!

Comment: So, if both weights are low, the full range of 1-100 is still possible, but the high values are just less likely? Or is the max reduced? This feels like the kind of question where if you could specify it more completely, the answer might suggest itself.

Comment: If one weight is 10 and the other is 90, will the distribution of values be the same as if one if 40 and the other is 60, or both weights are 50? In that case you can probably just average the two numbers. What does that number mean then? Is it just the mean value of the random numbers you want to get?

Comment: If both are low the full range is still possible, exactly.  I guess getting the average is probably the best way.  Such an obvious answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need more information for those weights: how *heavy* do they weigh on the probability for that index, and how much does that probability increase spread around to neighbouring indexes.

I will here assume that these parameters can be provided, and that the probabilities spread around with a normal distribution.

I would suggest to create an array with the probabilities for each of the indexes. You start out with a constant (e.g. 1) for each of them, which means all indexes have the same probability of being selected.

Then a function could apply one weight to it, given an index where the weight should be centred at, the weight itself (how much does it increase the existing "weight" at that index), and the spread (the standard deviation of the normal distribution with which the generated probability will be spread around).

Here is the code that does such a thing. It is not intended to be statistically sound, but I believe it will do the job in a satisfactory way:

```
function density($x, $median, $stddev) {
    // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Further_details
    return exp(-pow($x - $median,2)/(2*pow($stddev,2))/(2*pi()*$stddev));
}

function homogeneous_distribution($size) {
    return array_fill(0, $size, 1);
}

function add_weight(&$distr, $median, $weight, $spread) {
    foreach ($distr as $i => &$prob) {
        $prob += $weight * density($i, $median, $spread);
    }
}

function random_float() { // between 0 and 1 (exclusive)
    return mt_rand(0, mt_getrandmax() - 1) / mt_getrandmax();
}

function weighted_random($distr) {
    $r = random_float() * array_sum($distr);
    foreach ($distr as $i => $prob) {
        $r -= $prob;
        if ($r < 0) return $i;
    }
}

// Example use with 20 instead of 100.
$distr = homogeneous_distribution(20); // range is 0 .. 19
add_weight($distr, 0, 4, 1); // at index 0, put a weight of 4, spreading with 1
add_weight($distr, 16, 8, 0.5); // at index 16, put a weight of 8, spreading with 0.2

// Print distribution (weights for every index):
echo "DISTRIBUTION:\n";
print_r($distr);

// Get 10 weighted random indexes from this distribution:
echo "RANDOM SAMPLES:\n";
foreach (range(0, 10) as $i) {
    echo weighted_random($distr) . "\n";
}
```

See it run on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/MOKBF88935)